# Can I listen to non-VoIP audio captured in Wireshark

Tags: stream, wireshark, multicast, rtp

I am troubleshooting an Audio Over IP network system which uses multicast streams to pass audio over ethernet.

When a customer has pops/clicks in his or her audio, it usually means multicast flooding or some other network issue. I can use Wireshark to capture the packets and see this happening.

However, I would also like to be able to listen to the audio stream if possible so that I can hear what is happening. I can do this easily when I am working with VoIP calls but this is not VoIP/SIP.

I have turned on the RTP_RTSP and RTP_UDP protocols and can isolate the streams. But when I try to play one or save it as an .au file I am unable to do so. This is what they pretty much always look like when I hit "Play:"

[image]

Am I missing something, or is it only possible to play VoIP streams, not ordinary AoIP streams in Wireshark?

Answer (score 1):

First, the Wireshark audio player supports a limited number of codecs see [here](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChTelPlayingCalls.html#:%7E:text=9.2.1.%C2%A0Supported%20codecs). Check if your encoding is in that list. Second, the number of packets in you RTP stream looks too big for any "regular" codec: 1063 for ~6 seconds of recording (for example, G711 with 10 milliseconds sampling gives you only ~600 packets)

Comment: Our audio is uncompressed for broadcast so in this case we're looking at .25 ms packet timing. Should be about 4000 packets per second of audio.

Comment: I guess I'm really asking if non-VoIP audio can even be played at all...I have never had a problem with VoIP phone calls but can't seem to make it play a normal non-VoIP RTP stream.